# Programm with PyAutoGui working in Python Shell but not in Command Prompt

Tags: python, command-prompt, pyautogui

so I have a problem with PyAutoGui!
I have this code:

```
import pyautogui
import time
import sys
import os
def run():
    time.sleep(3)
    pyautogui.moveRel(30, 30)

    pyautogui.click()
    time.sleep(0.1)
    pyautogui.click()

    pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'c')

    pyautogui.moveTo(1903, 2)

    pyautogui.click()

    pyautogui.moveTo(906, 1060)

    pyautogui.click()
    pyautogui.click()

    intervalvariable = 0.025
    intervalvariablebetweenwords = 0.4
    print("Please enter the first word and press Strg and v:")
    FullText = input()
    buttonlocation = None
    while buttonlocation == None:
        buttonlocation = pyautogui.locateOnScreen("button.png")
    buttonx, buttony = pyautogui.center(buttonlocation)
    pyautogui.moveTo(buttonx, buttony)
    pyautogui.moveRel(-20, 20)
    pyautogui.click()
    words = FullText.split(" ")
    for i in range(0, len(words)):
        if i == len(words)-4:
            intervalvariable = 0.015
            intervalvariablebetweenwords = 0
        pyautogui.typewrite(words[i], interval=intervalvariable);
        pyautogui.typewrite(" ", interval=0);
        time.sleep(intervalvariablebetweenwords)
    os.system('cls')
    print("Do You want to go again? If so, type 'YES' if not type something     else!")
    Again = input()
    if Again == "YES":
        os.system('cls')
        run()
    else:
        os.system('cls')
       sys.exit("Ok!")

run()
```

**And if i try to run it in the Python Shell it functions perfectly, but when I run it in the Command Prompt it just crashes** at the point, where it tries to find the image (Its an image of some text, where it orients itself).

When it searches the image in the Python shell it searches about 1 second and finds it and everything works but I cant even get the error Message from the Command Prompt, so I would be pleased if you could help me!

**Excuse my writing im German. :D**

Comment: If you can't copy-paste the error message in CMD, could you take a picture? That'll help with figuring out the problem. But also, are you running CMD in the same folder as your `button.png` file?

Comment: @Niayesh Isky 19     I am just double clicking the .py file, so that would solve your Question right? and btw the command prompt closes too fast, I can only see, that it prints much text (Im guessing an Error) and then closes a millisecond after

Comment: @Niayesh Isky See comment above

Comment: Oh, I see, you have your system set up to run .py files with python automatically. But try running it from CMD instead: open CMD, `cd` to the folder of your .py file, ensure that `button.png` is also in that folder, and then call `python name_of_file.py`. This will ensure CMD stays open even after the error message.

Comment: @Niayesh Isky  Ok I tried that, but what happend was: Everything functioned perfectly and no error occured. When I open the Python Script and press F5 everything works, but when i double click it doesn't work anymore and I don't know why. And btw I checked what app opens it when i double click and it says Python so I guess that should normally work

Comment: Yes, but most likely, when you open python with double-click, the executable opens in the default python location, which is not the folder where your `button.png` is stored, so the script won't know where to look for the picture. If you really want the program to work with double-click, either add that folder to your PATH variable (this is recommended), or change all of your relative paths to absolute paths. This should fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks that worked for me! ;) I used pyinstaller to make it an exe File and now it works